# Problem with ASP.NET Custom Validator for a Comma Separated List of Email Addresses

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation

I followed a [blog post here](http://renditionprotocol.blogspot.com/2007/06/aspnet-custom-validator-for-comma.html) to use a custom validator to validate a list of emails. However, the Regex expression in the article:

```
Regex emailRegEx = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
                       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

allows this email address through:

```
"APL@domain.com 123@domain.com"
```

which is clearly invalid.

How can I change it to flag this as invalid?

Note: When you use the core RegEx Validator with the SAME regex expression it DOES catch that email, so perhaps it is a problem with the matching options?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex emailRegEx = new Regex(@"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It looks like you need to terminate your regular expression.  Check the '^' at the start and the "$" at the end of the expression above.

Comment: +1 this is the answer. The reason the RegularExpressionValidator control works for the OP is because these anchors are assumed, and they match correctly as a result. However, the Regex class assumes nothing, so they must be specified explicitly.