# How to check comma separated email addresses with regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I want to check a comma separated email addresses with `regex` in [Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) validation and I have created below `regex` for email but it is not working for me.

```
regex: /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i
```

I want to allow email like this: `test1test.com, test2@test.com, test3@test.com`

Here is my validation example code:

```
$rules = array(
    'email' => 'regex:/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i',
);
$messages = [
    'email.regex' => 'Please enter valid Email.',
];

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412725/how-to-match-a-comma-separated-list-of-emails-with-regex. You may either use that approach (`^(` + your regex + `,?)+$`) or use something more PCRE-like `/^([_a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,3})(?:,(?1))*$/i`

Comment: Email isn't quite that simple to validate: https://hexillion.com/samples/ < scroll down to the Regular Expressions section.

Comment: Comma's are not allowed in e-mail addresses, so you could also explode on the comma, trim the results and use `filter_var()` to check each entry individually.

Comment: why not explode the string by comma and validate each element via built-in laravel email validator rule?

Comment: isn't it an option to use explode and check them in foreach?

Comment: @AlexAndrei I don't know how to do that in Laravel.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
foreach(explode(',', $sEmailAddresses) AS $sEmailAddress) {
$bValid |= filter_var($sEmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
 }

 $sResult = ($bValid) ? 'Both are valid' : 'One of them are not';
```

Comment: don't use explode in the foreach, add it to a variable first. using a function in foreach is bad for performance

Comment: You also need to trim the individual strings as leading or ending spaces will invalidate an e-mail address.

Comment: @PaulRoefs Why? `explode` is executed once.

Comment: another thing I noticed is that this will probably give 'One of them are not' when both are not valid too

Answer (score 0):

This is java-script validation

```
 var emails='test1test.com,test2@test.com,test3@test.com'; 
    var regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
     var result = emails.replace(/\s/g, "").split(",");  
                    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
                        if(!regex.test(result[i])) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`replace()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L532) method of `Request` class to turn input into an array containing email addresses then do an array validation on it:

```
// Split form input value on commas followed by any number of spaces (returns an array)
$request->replace(array('email' => preg_split('~, *~', $request->email)));
// How we should define our validator rule
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email.*' => 'email',
]);
// Turn back to our first value
$request->email = implode(', ', $request->email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an alternative,

```
/^([_a-z0-9\-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]{2,}\.)*([a-z]{2,4})(,([_a-z0-9\-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]{2,}\.)*([a-z]{2,4}))*$/
```

To verify your email regex.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to @Alex Andrei's comment:

Below you will find an example of the function I used to get the results you're looking for using PHP explode() to separate the emails. Obviously in order to get the exact functionality that you need, you should really dig into that documentation :)

```
public function validateEmail()
    {
        $emails = "john@email.com,jack@email.com,notanemail,jill@email.com";
        $explodedEmails = explode(",", $emails);


        foreach ($explodedEmails as $email)
        {
            $validator = \Validator::make(
                array('individualEmail' => $email),
                array('individualEmail' => 'email') 
            );

            if ($validator->passes())
            {
                echo "Email correct <br />";
            }
            elseif($validator->fails())
            {
                echo "Email not correct <br />";

            }

        };

    }
```

This echoes:

```
Email correct 
Email correct 
Email not correct 
Email correct
```