# Regular expression for 5 comma separated email id

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I trying to validate 5 comma separated email id in one regular expression.
I currntly using below regex

```
^([\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4},?)+$
```

This is valid for one email id.

I would like to know how I can achieve the same, any small inputs on the same is also greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some valid and not valid examples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match a comma separated list of emails with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412725/how-to-match-a-comma-separated-list-of-emails-with-regex)

Comment: are you sure your regex is for email? it seems a phone number.

Comment: sa@gmail.com,a@gmail.com like that i can add only 5 email Id is valid.  sa@gamil.com,sa@gamil.com like thai i add 6 or more email Id is invalid.

Comment: You shouldn't approach validating all the email addresses at the same time, it's difficult to show to the user what's wrong. Split your data into an `Array` and then validate each email and the `Array.prototype.length` value. `'abc@bca.ab,abc@bca.cab,aaabc@bca.ab,abc@bca.ab'.split(',').map(validator);`

Comment: sorry @Sierrodc its my mistake

Comment: Try it like this - `^[\w+.%-]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?:[\w+.%-]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}){0,4}$`. Basically: `^<EMAIL_RX>(?:,<EMAIL_RX>){0,4}$`. Note that if you put an unescaped `-` in `[\w+-.%]` it will form a range. Either escape it, or better, put at the start/end of the character class (`[-\w+.%]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, fix the pattern: `-` in between two chars inside a character class forms a range. So, the email part of your regex should be `[-\w+.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}` (note the position of `-` in the first character class, in the second, it is OK to put it between a shorthand character class `\w` and the next char).

Next, to match 1 to 5 comma-separated emails, you need to match the first one, and then match 0 to 4 emails. And add anchors around the pattern to make sure the pattern matches the whole string:

```
^[-\w+.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?:,[-\w+.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}){0,4}$
```

Basically, `^<EMAIL>(?:,<EMAIL>){0,4}$`:

- `^` - start of string
- `<EMAIL>` - an email pattern of yours
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group acting as a container for a sequence of patterns:

  - `,`  - a comma
  - `<EMAIL>` - an email pattern of yours
- `){0,4}` - zero to four occurrences of these sequences above
- `$` - end of string.

Another idea is to split with `,` and then validate:

```js
var s = "abc@gg.com,abc2@gg.com,abc3@gg.com,abc4@gg.com,abc5@gg.com";
var re = /^[-\w+.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/;
var items = s.split(",");
if (items.length <= 5 && items.filter(function(x) { return re.test(x); }).length === items.length ) {
   console.log("VALID => ", items);
} else {
   console.log("INVALID!");
}
```

Comment: Its working but I want atmost 5 email enter.1 email id enter is also valid.but 6 email enter is not valid.

Comment: So, my initial assumption was valid. I have reverted the answer to what I posted initially.

Comment: Its working fine but I want to enter atmost 5 email id.I enter 3 or 4 email id is also valid. but 6 email id enter is not valid.

Comment: [I fixed the single regex part](https://regex101.com/r/SblsSs/1). And I have fixed the JS solution right now.

Comment: Can I do same in case of Mobile Number using regex?

Comment: I do but only one mobile number accepted.                                      
 Regex:-  ^((\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$

Comment: Your phone regex is `(\+91-?|0)?[0-9]{10}`, so use `^(\+91-?|0)?[0-9]{10}(?:,(\+91-?|0)?[0-9]{10}){0,4}$` or use the `^(\+91-?|0)?[0-9]{10}$` in the JS code like above.

Answer (score -1):

Below regex for javaScript you can use for multiple comma separated email id, hope this work for you

```
/^(\w+((-\w+)|(\.\w+))*\@[A-Za-z0-9]+((\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}\s*?,?\s*?)+$/
```

Comment: This regex will also match [strings with trailing whitespaces and a comma](https://regex101.com/r/zGs4bl/1). It is also not optimized since `[.-]` is matching a dot or `-` linearly, while `(\.|-)` will cause backtracking.

Comment: And besides, it matches more than 5 comma separated emails.

Comment: yes i know i explain Below regex for javaScript you can use for multiple comma separated email id, hope this work for you