# Match joined AmPm hours with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript

I have input string in next format : `12:00am|1:20PM|9:30Pm`

I need to have in output array of hours like : `[12:00am, 1:20PM, 9:30Pm]`

But before I shoudl match it with regex.

I have some regex to match AmPm hours and I tried to add `|` to match full string
`\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm]))([|])?`. This regex matches string `12:00am|1:20PM|9:30Pm` but also matches string `12:00am|1:20PM}9:30Pm` which isn't correct.

Where is my mistake in my regex and how can I return expected array.

Thanks

Comment: What a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175731/regular-expression-for-5-comma-separated-email-id). Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175731/regular-expression-for-5-comma-separated-email-id#comment75366499_44175731). It is advisable to split with `"|"` and check if all the items match `^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm])$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks, I will check it

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/4xmzw5p3/1/. So, split first, then validate. Does it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm]))([|])?` does not require `|` as `[|]?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of this char. This regex matches `12:00am|1:20PM}9:30Pm` as it finds `12:00am` and calls it  a day (i.e. returns a valid match).

You need to split the string with `|` and validate each item against `/^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm])$/` pattern.

```js
var s = "12:00am|1:20PM|9:30Pm";
var re = /^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]([AaPp][Mm])$/;
var items = s.split("|");
if (items.filter(function(x) { return re.test(x); }).length === items.length) {
   console.log("VALID => ", items);
} else {
 console.log("INVALID!");
}
```

Note you may use a regex to pre-validate the string, but it is just more cumbersome:

```js
var s = "12:00am|1:20PM|9:30Pm";
var re_block = "(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm])";
var re = new RegExp("^" + re_block + "(?:\\|" + re_block + ")*$");
var isValid = re.test(s);
console.log(isValid ? s.split("|") : "Invalid!");
```

The regex will look like `/^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm])(?:\|(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm]))*$/` and it will validate a string that starts with the time substring, and then has 0 or more occurrences of time substrings up to the string end. See the [pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCS2OG/1).